# Where to watch .hack legally?

Tags: .hack

I watched [.hack//Quantum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.hack//Quantum) on Netflix and loved it.  I would like to watch the rest of the [.hack shows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.hack#Anime) as well, but they seem to not be on Netflix or Crunchyroll.  Is there anywhere else I can stream them from legally?

Comment: Funimation apparently has rights to a number of .hack shows but according to website comments, hasn't released them online: http://www.funimation.com/blog/2013/07/18/funimation-acquires-hack/

Comment: @hungerartist that's surprising, i thought they had the rights for US distribution already. almost been a year and still no streaming could mean they just plan to BluRay the series

Comment: @Memor-X: most of the shows (at least when I searched for it) definitely couldn't be streamed, other than what seems to be a couple OVA's from one series.

Comment: If you want to watch it for free, please google search. No-one will tell you here on this site.

Comment: @MiharuDante it's not the matter if it's free or not but if it's legal, Madman's screening room is free to my knowledge and i'm quite sure Funimation is free but they Geoblock even their youtube videos

Comment: How do you determine if a site is legal or not? Should we not give the asker a place where to buy it like your answer.

Comment: It just avoids further confusion and debate.

Comment: @MiharuDante legality of streaming has something to do with copywrite and licences, i use Anime News Network at times, an example would be [Sword Art Online](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=13858), under English Companies you have Internet Streaming, to my knowledge those places should be the only places which are legally able to stream SAO in english (subbed or dubbed), likewise if you look at Japanese companies. there's nothing wrong getting a Japanese PSN Account and watching SAO that way though

Comment: @MiharuDante there's also [this list](http://organizationasg.kokidokom.net/2013/02/18/this-is-how-you-can-watch-anime-legally-in-2013/) of legal sites. any site outside these probably is not doing it legaly and as such could be slapped as a Cease an Demises Order from Licences Holders, kinda like with Scalators. with all that said, i don't know ever site so i try and ask in the chat first if a site is legal or not

Comment: I have edited the question, so that it asks specifically for legal sources, as per [this meta post](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/796/49). This should be the action taken when in doubt.

Comment: @JNat Thanks, I just thought all questions of this type would be assumed to only dealing with legal options.

Comment: @DavidStarkey And your assumption was not incorrect. However, saying it explicitly only benefits the post. And if the users says "I didn't mean to ask about legal sources", we'll close it without doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure on watching the series online but you can buy [.hack//SIGN](http://www.madman.com.au/catalogue/view/4619/-hack-sign-collection-fatpack), [.hack//Legend of the Twilight](http://www.madman.com.au/catalogue/view/11948/-hack-legend-of-the-twilight-collection-slimpack) and [.hack//ROOTS](http://www.madman.com.au/catalogue/view/8120/-hack-roots-collection-fatpack) on Madman. [.hack//G.U. Trilogy](http://www.hanabee.com.au/index.php/store/hackgutrilogy-dvd.html) can be brought from Hanabee but it pales in comparison to the game in my opinion. all of these are Australian so they are in Region 4 but you should be able to find them on your local distribution site(s) but it wont be a problem if you have a region free player.

.hack//Terminal Disk is a special that came with .hack//G.U Pre-orders which details the events between the last episode of .hack//SIGN (After the Game) and the first episode of .hack//ROOTS (before the .hack//G.U games) but ignores most of what happens in .hack//Legend of the Twilight, recapping the original games, Aura's disappearance, Project G.U, the R.A Program which destroyed most of *The World* and the start of *The World:R2*. i did have a playlist of them on youtube but the videos have been deleted

.hack//Liminality came with the original .hack Games but i didn't get the final episode when i got the last game so i had to download it, each episode follows in line with the game it was released, the last episode being set during the final battle (the server Helba set up to help combat Corbenik).

.hack//Gift should be included with the .hack//Sign fatpack i linked to likewise with .hack//G.U. Returner with .hack//ROOTS. gift is a weird OVA but Returner is like the last episode of SIGN where it concludes the games.

the .hack//G.U games have Online Jack in the game aswell along with a number of 4Koma episodes along with i think a couple of episode of .hack//ROOTS (never watched them since i had them on DVD)

i have no information on .hack//The Movie or Thanatos Report however according to your wikipedia link both are with .hack//Versus game, the first one being hybrid with the game while the second one being unlocked from gameplay much like Online Jack.

SIGN, LotT and ROOTS are a bit old (over a decade) and quite sure was before the concept of streaming videos so i'm not sure where you could view them. [VIZ Media](http://www.viz.com/anime/streaming) or [Aniplex](http://www.aniplexusa.com/watch/) might have them i'm not sure as i tend opt for owning the DVDs and wtahcing them in my own time.